# Can't see TabItem content in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, tabitem

So here is my problem. I have a WPF application basically composed of a TabControl with many TabItems. I have each TabItem declared in separated classes, and what I do is insert them into the TabControl of the MainWindow like this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCtrl" Grid.Column="2" Margin="89.765,29.697,89.766,33.697"
            Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}" TabStripPlacement="Left"
            SelectionChanged="tabCtrl_SelectionChanged">
        <TabControl.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF9F9F9" Opacity="0.6"/>
        </TabControl.Background>
        <local:WelcomeTab Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="welcomeTab"/>
        <local:Step1Tab Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="step1Tab"/>
        <local:Step2Tab Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="step2Tab"/>
        <local:Step3Tab Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="step3Tab"/>
        <local:Step4Tab Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="step4Tab"/>
</TabControl>
```

I use Expression Blend to edit the tabs, and as I'm using this method, I have to edit each tab in their own class. The problem is that when I want to do it, I must do it directly in the XAML because all I see of the TabItem is the header.

The XAML of this tab, for example, is something like this:

```
<TabItem x:Class="Foo.Step1Tab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Foo.Properties"
         x:Name="step1Tab" IsEnabled="true"
         IsManipulationEnabled="True"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.step1Tab}" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
    <Content of the tab>
</TabItem>
```

Is there anything I can do to be able to see the elements of the tab and manipulate them?

Comment: Have the same problem. It is not limited to blend but affects the Visual Studio designer, too. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164072/wpf-custom-tabitem-controlls-not-displayed-in-visual-studio-designer