# WPF Custom TabItem - Controls not displayed in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, custom-controls

I created a custom TabItem with a DockPanel and a Button in it.

XAML:

```
<TabItem
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MovieDB.UI.UserControlls.SearchTab" d:DesignWidth="500.038" d:DesignHeight="309.055">

    <DockPanel Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </DockPanel>
</TabItem>
```

C#:

```
namespace MovieDB.UI.UserControlls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für SearchTab.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SearchTab : TabItem
    {
        private SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results;

        public SearchTab()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Header = "Suche";
        }

        public SearchTab(SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results):this()
        {
            this.updateSearch(results);
        }

        public void updateSearch(SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results)
        {
            clear();
            if(results.TotalResults == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                this.results = results;
                Debug.WriteLine("Results: " + results.Results.Count());
            }
        }

        private void clear()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If launch my program the button is displayed (Screenshot 2). But the button and i guess the panel itselve does noch show up in the Visual Studio 2015 Designer (Screenshot 1).

Where is the Problem?

[image: Screenshot Designer]
[image: Screenshot running Programm]

Comment: The code you provided does not get me to a buildable state to test your issue. The XAML part of your code seems strange to me as TabItem is your base class. A question, why don't you create a user control that contains your dock panel and button with background search code and add that to the Tablitems in your tab control instead?

Answer (score 3):

If you put the TabItem in a TabControl it works fine.I think that's the Problem.
The designer needs a navigation control like TabControl,Window Page etc. as root.

```
<TabControl x:Class="CustomControls.tab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            d:DesignWidth="500.038" d:DesignHeight="309.055">
<TabItem>
    <DockPanel Background="#FFE5E5E5">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </DockPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: The problem is, that i have a tab controll in my MainWindow. And i add a custom TabItem (the searchItem) programmatically in case someone type in the searchfield. So putting it in the TapControll is not an option becaus i add an item to an existing controll.

Comment: It was just an explanation why it won't show up in designer.But you said when you launch your app it works.Is it important for you to see it in the designer? here is a similar thread : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422006/xaml-designer-doesnt-show-content-of-a-usercontrol)

Comment: It is more comfortable if I can use the designer. At the moment I change the TapItem-Tag to Page-Tag and edit it in the designer. After that I change it back to TapItem to build the App. It's a workaround but pretty anoying do to it every time.

Comment: While this is not the solution it's very near. I could manage to make it work just fine if I transform the tabitem into UserControls and include the usercontrols inside a tabitem on the main window.

Answer (score 1):

What you did should work. But it doesn't, and I'll later try to show why.

But first, my workaround:

- open designer, and right-click on it,
- select: *Edit Additional Templates*, then *Edit Generated Content*, then *Create Empty...* Give your new `DataTemplate` a name, say '*DataTemplate1*'

Designer will generate some code - an empty `DataTemplate` with a key *DataTemplate1*, and it will add your to `TabItem` the `ContentTemplate` attribute, with *DataTemplate1* assigned to it (by `DynamicResource`).

Now move the content of your `TabItem` to the *DataTemplate1*. The designer should correctly display your layout.

If you close and reopen your *SearchTab* control, you'll find that you can't see the content again. To have it back right click on the designer, select *Edit Additional Template*, then *Edit Generated Content*, then *Edit Current*.

Why the designer couldn't load your *SearchTab*? If you right-click on the designer and select *Edit Template*, then *Edit a Copy...* you'll have `TabItem` style generated. The header of the `TabItem` is displayed by the ContentPresenter, while the TabItem's content must by displayed inside the *innerBorder* `Border`. This border has `Opacity` set to zero, and it's being changed to 1 by `MultiTriggers`, which are dependent on the `TabControl`. The `TabControl` in your case doesn't exist, so all the bindings are broken. Which suggests, that changing a default `Style` for 'TabItem', would also solve your problem.

Comment: I think this is really a greate answer that gives some insights. BTW it works! What do you mean by 'changing Style for TabItem'? Is it possible to create a style with Opacity != zero or something? And is it possible to permanently display the DataTemplate instead of the ContentPresenter?

Comment: And how can I get my View->ViewModel binding working again?

Comment: @anhoppe. If I remember well (I don't have that code with me), I've been playing with   the Style for TabItem, so that ContentTemplate was binded (TemplateBinding) to Content. This worked. I'd need to spend some time on it for a deeper answer. For View->ViewModel bindings working you need to set DataType on DataTemplate (DataType="{x:Type YourType}")

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not have my dev machine to work with, I can only offer a suggestion.  For whatever you want on your tab item control, why not put all your controls in a custom user control or grid with the premise that you KNOW you will be adding it to tab control that is dynamically added to your tab page.

The tab item needs its proper parent tab control to render it in the designer.  But if you build everything as a standard control make it look and operate as you expect.

Then at run-time, add your tab item, then add the custom control to your dynamically added tab item and see if that works for you.  You apparently have all the other components / processes working.  Even if your sample control was just a label, textbox or something similar.

Comment: After struggeling around with swiszcs answer I finally came to use your proposal. It's simple and effective. Don't get me wrong, I really appreciate swiszcz post since it helps to understand the problem and it is an unconventional solution but it seems to have too many flaws. What I like best with this approach is that the binding is not broken when I pull out the TabItem content in a designated UserControl. It's perfectly transparent to the rest of the code.